$\frac{dy}{dx} = 1/(5y^2+2y$). Need a solution in terms of y.
$\frac{dy}{dx}=1/(5y^2+2y$)
Easy to solve for $x$, ie $x = 5\frac{y^3}{3} + y^2$. But how do I solve for y?
Ok, so to edit and try to add some context…it’s from a textbook (Cambridge Specialist Maths Units 3&4. It’s in a set of questions that require you to solve differential equations in the dependent variable, and all the other questions find x in terms of y then rearrange to give y in terms of x, since the original d.e. are given as dy/dx = …
For this question though, the answer is only given as below. My query is, if $x = 5\frac{y^3}{3} + y^2$, then how do I rearrange this for y? The CAS gives some composite function which is a combination of cos and arcsin, but I can’t figure how to do this without the CAS?
Note that I've taken the integration constant to be zero for simplicity.

See separation of variables.

See cubic equation.

Please do not post your question more than once

Does this answer your question? $\frac{dy}{dx} = 1/(5y^2+2y$). Solution in terms of $x$ is easy but once I have x in terms of y (see below) how do I rearrange this for y?

I wouldn't ask my question more than once if someone could actually help me! My original question has an error which I fixed but I still haven't seen anyone say why the CAS gives me some function in cos and arcsin when I rearrange x=(5/3)y^3+y^2 for y??

What you're looking for is a solution for a cubic equation in terms of $y$, i.e. $\frac{5}{3}y^3 + y^2 - (x + C) = 0$. From the Wikipedia article @RobertIsrael linked, it mentions how cubic equations can be solved in terms of trigonometric and inverse trigonometric functions after it is depressed, which might be what the CAS is using to solve the cubic equation. Alternatively, the solution can be expressed in nested radicals, which isn't very pretty either.

@Nightytime THANKYOU - I guess I should thank Robert Israel as well, I just didn't get that far through the article to find the trig solutions! Much appreciated.
